# Make a card in Apple Wallet do the request based on location

Tags: geolocation

I have done creating an Apple certified pass to Wallet app.

According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/) we can toggle "local push notification" with text on it, if user is close to some position (by GPS coordinates).

But also I need to have this event registred on my server, in order to send a message in social media as well.

Any ideas how to make it?

Answer (score 1):

The Pass in itself cannot register the event on your server. You will need an accompanying app (possibly using PassKit) in order to that.

Comment: By saying `accompanying app`, you mean web service or another installed app on the phone?

Comment: Installed app on the phone.